Proof of Kakutani fixed-point theorem
I'm reading the following proof of the Kakutani fixed-point theorem, written by Prof. McMullen in his functional analysis notes.  I don't understand the proof beyond the point where he appeals to Krein-Milman: how is the limit in "we have $z' = \lim g_n z$" obtained, and what is happening in the following lines that leads to a contradiction? I know the conclusion is that $L$ cannot contain a nontrivial interval, but I don't see how the back half of this paragraph works. Thank you!

In this context Milman's theorem implies that $z'\in\text{ext}(L)\subset Gz$. Now since the space of isometries on a compact space is itself compact (hence separable) it follows that we can extract a subsequence $g_n$ such that $g_nz\to z'$
